# C# and SharpZipLib encording error

Tags: c#, compression, sharpziplib

I am using SharpZipLib to compress with C#.

but, If any file's name is written in Korean, file name is changed.

I think I need to change encording ?
What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

```
ZipConstants.DefaultCodePage = System.Text.Encoding.Default.CodePage;
```

See http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/1954/36951.aspx